# Putting text in different registers in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I'm reading the practical vim book on page 30 it talks about registers. Can you have different assigned registers? The default register is 0 once I put something in reg 0 how can I keep this in there and put something in reg 1 then 2, 3 ect

I want to store tags in these registers so I can quickly just paste them in.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registers 0-9 have special purpose, actually. When you cut something longer than one line, the contents of your register 9 is discarded, the contents of register 8 moves to register 9, 7 to 8, etc. and the contents of register 0 moves to 1. Then the text you cut appears in 0.

But you can freely use named registers (`a`-`z`) and they won't be overwritten unless you tell Vim to do so. For this instead of <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> do <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to copy or delete to register `a`. Using <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> will append to register `a` instead of overwriting its contents.

To paste use <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. To paste in Insert Mode use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

For more info read `:help registers`.